# Not able to run Junit in Eclipse

Tags: junit4, sap-commerce-cloud, eclipse-mars

Im using eclipse Mars 4.5.0 and when i try to run JUnit , getting the following error
 [image]

[image]

Comment: Well, have you checked that the project config that is referenced by the classpath exists?  There is no way we can help you with this without knowing more context including what you have tried.

Comment: i've a class where im trying to execute an JUnit Test case for that class, when i do RightClick->Run-As->JUnit Test , getting the following error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have build path issues in your workspace.
You are missing the "config" project in your workspace at least.
You have to do "Import" -> "Existing Projects into Workspace" -> select your hybris home folder -> check the "config" project.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a issue with Java build path. So please check with Java Build Path in Eclipse.

Comment: What all jar files need to be added? i've given java build path-> class varialbe ->JRE 1.8.0_121 ,JUnit path

Answer (score 0):

When you want to run tests in eclipse, you need to have a workspace, that can be built. Fix the errors in your workspace and make sure all projects referenced by your setup are imported in your workspace.

Perhaps this helps:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Eclipse+workspace+errors+-+A+Complete+guide